# Can a constant be considered as 1x1 matrix?

Tags: matrices

A constant $c$ can be considered as 1 x 1 matrix $\;$ $( c )$ , it makes sense in terms of matrix inverse, matrix addition etc but the multiplication of a constant is possible to any matrix ( by multiplying all entries of matrix with it ) but if we consider constant as 1 x 1 matrix ,its multiplication with other matrices should not make sense ( as $m$ x $n$ matrix can be multiplies by $n$ x $k$ matrix only ).
So why is constant multiplication defined the way it is and can we consider a constant as a 1 x 1 matrix ?

Comment: Scalar multiplication is defined the way it is because it is useful, and otherwise you seem to have answered your question: Sometimes, depending on context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it is convenient to treat a scalar as a $1\times 1$ matrix as we consider the base field itself as a vector space of dimension 1 and multiplication by the scalar as a linear transformation. In the same sense a scalar can be considered a vector on which we may perform such linear transformations.

When a scalar is multiplied by a matrix of arbitrary dimensions, this also treats the scalar as a linear transformation, but if we were to write this linear transformation in matrix form it would be a diagonal matrix of the correct dimensions for the multiplication to make sense. We could treat the matrices themselves as vectors in a vector space of dimension $mn$, in which case the "matrixness" of the matrix goes away and we have an $mn\times mn$ diagonal matrix. I'm either case all of the diagonal entries would be equal to the scalar.

In short, mathematical objects of the same name may wear many hats.

Answer (score 3):

Those would be two different types of products.

On one hand, if you have a $m\times n$ and a $n\times l$ matrices you define their product, which is a $m\times l$ matrix. In this sense matrices form a [monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid), and as you say the product by a scalar makes sense in some cases when you consider it as the product by a $1\times 1$ matrix, because there is a bijection between scalars and $1\times 1$ matrices.

On the other hand, *scalar multiplication* is an example of the so called **[actions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action)** of a group on a set, in this case, the reals acting in the space of matrices.

In your example, the former one is a particular case of the latter one, but they are essentially different.

**Edit**: If you insist on using matrix multiplication to represent multiplication by scalars, all you need to do is take multiples of the identity matrix of the right dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The *scalar multiplication* operation is useful because of convenience/concisiveness. If the scalar is an integer s, s*M = M+M+..+M (s times).

Sure we can do away with it by always using instead *matrix multiplication* operation with matrix diagonal([s,s,...s]); this also applies to scaling a vector, by the way.
But s*M is shorter than even "diag(s)*M".